# what is the matter with the select_string wrapped in py_sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite

I can select a record in sqlitemanager (firefox plugin).Please see the attatchment of the selected record.The database is here , http://pan.baidu.com/s/1eQ04tlo .
You can download it and test the sql statement.

```
select  capital.代码 as code,quote.close as close, quote.close*capital.股份总数/10000 as market_cap,     
    balance.负债合计/balance.资产总计 as debt_ratio,                                                        
    profit.归属于母公司所有者的净利润/balance.'所有者权益(或股东权益)合计' as roe,            
    profit.归属于母公司所有者的净利润/balance.'负债和所有者权益(或股东权益)总计' as roa ,                  
    quote.close*capital.股份总数/profit.归属于母公司所有者的净利润 as pe,                                   
    quote.close*capital.股份总数/balance.资产总计  as pb                                                     
    from profile,capital,quote,balance,profit                                                               
    where capital.代码=300001
    and profile.代码=capital.代码  
    and profile.代码=quote.code   
    and profile.代码=balance.代码
    and profile.代码=profit.代码  
    and quote.date="20140523"     
    and balance.报告日期="20131231"      
    and profit.报告日期="20131231";
```

[image]

When i wrap it in python code ,i can't get the selected record,What is the matter?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os,re,sqlite3
db_name='china.sqlite'
target_dir='e:\\workspace\\data\\'
con = sqlite3.connect(target_dir+db_name)
cur=con.cursor()
select_str='''select  capital.代码 as code,quote.close as close, quote.close*capital.股份总数/10000 as market_cap,     
    balance.负债合计/balance.资产总计 as debt_ratio,                                                        
    profit.归属于母公司所有者的净利润/balance.'所有者权益(或股东权益)合计' as roe,            
    profit.归属于母公司所有者的净利润/balance.'负债和所有者权益(或股东权益)总计' as roa ,                  
    quote.close*capital.股份总数/profit.归属于母公司所有者的净利润 as pe,                                   
    quote.close*capital.股份总数/balance.资产总计  as pb                                                     
    from profile,capital,quote,balance,profit                                                               
    where  capital.代码=300001   
    and profile.代码=capital.代码  
    and profile.代码=quote.code   
    and profile.代码=balance.代码
    and profile.代码=profit.代码  
    and quote.date='20140523'     
    and balance.报告日期='20131231'      
    and profit.报告日期='20131231';'''
cur.execute(select_str)
print(cur.fetchall())
```

it's so strange for me to understand that that code1 can run,code2 can not run.

code1

```
import os,re,sqlite3
db_name='china.sqlite'
target_dir='e:\\workspace\\data\\'
con = sqlite3.connect(target_dir+db_name)
cur=con.cursor()
select_str='''select  capital.代码 as code,quote.close as close, quote.close*capital.股份总数/10000 as market_cap,     
    balance.负债合计/balance.资产总计 as debt_ratio,                                                        
    profit.归属于母公司所有者的净利润/balance.'所有者权益(或股东权益)合计' as roe,            
    profit.归属于母公司所有者的净利润/balance.'负债和所有者权益(或股东权益)总计' as roa ,                  
    quote.close*capital.股份总数/profit.归属于母公司所有者的净利润 as pe,                                   
    quote.close*capital.股份总数/balance.资产总计  as pb                                                     
    from profile,capital,quote,balance,profit                                                               
    where  capital.代码='300001'  
    and profile.代码='300001'  
    and quote.code='300001'  
    and balance.代码='300001'
    and profit.代码='300001'
    and quote.date='20140523'     
    and balance.报告日期='20131231'      
    and profit.报告日期='20131231';'''
cur.execute(select_str)
print(cur.fetchall())
```

code2

```
import os,re,sqlite3
db_name='china.sqlite'
target_dir='e:\\workspace\\data\\'
con = sqlite3.connect(target_dir+db_name)
cur=con.cursor()
select_str='''select  capital.代码 as code,quote.close as close, quote.close*capital.股份总数/10000 as market_cap,     
    balance.负债合计/balance.资产总计 as debt_ratio,                                                        
    profit.归属于母公司所有者的净利润/balance.'所有者权益(或股东权益)合计' as roe,            
    profit.归属于母公司所有者的净利润/balance.'负债和所有者权益(或股东权益)总计' as roa ,                  
    quote.close*capital.股份总数/profit.归属于母公司所有者的净利润 as pe,                                   
    quote.close*capital.股份总数/balance.资产总计  as pb                                                     
    from profile,capital,quote,balance,profit                                                               
    where  capital.代码=300001   
    and profile.代码=capital.代码  
    and profile.代码=quote.code   
    and profile.代码=balance.代码
    and profile.代码=profit.代码  
    and quote.date='20140523'     
    and balance.报告日期='20131231'      
    and profit.报告日期='20131231';'''
cur.execute(select_str)
print(cur.fetchall())
```

In my point of view ,cod1 is equal to code2 logically ,there is no difference between them.
Is there difference between

```
where  capital.代码='300001'  
and profile.代码='300001'  
and quote.code='300001'  
and balance.代码='300001'
and profit.代码='300001'
```

and

```
where  capital.代码=300001   
and profile.代码=capital.代码  
and profile.代码=quote.code   
and profile.代码=balance.代码
and profile.代码=profit.代码
```

??

when i quote the code and get the right result ,so the reason of problem remain unknown.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't downloaded the database since it's about 250 megabytes, and that's far too much to download to answer a simple question. If you want people to download the database, I suggest creating a small database with just a few records, the ones in your question.

Now for the actual answer: when you put quotes around the number 300001, you're searching for a string. When you omit the quotes, you're searching for an integer. [The SQLite manual](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) says that integers will never compare equal to strings (SQLite calls it a TEXT value):

> An INTEGER or REAL value is less than any TEXT or BLOB value.

So your WHERE clause is never comparing equal when you search for an integer, because the actual value is a string. That's why you have to put quotes around "300001" is working.

**UPDATE**: The original version of my answer said "the actual value is an integer", which was backwards. After looking at the SQLite3 database that the OP posted, I see that the "代码" fields (for those who don't read Chinese, that translates roughly as "source code") are defined as TEXT fields in his schema. So I've edited my answer to swap integers and strings.

**UPDATE 2**: It seems, from the screenshots you've posted of sqlitemanager, that it is converting the integer values in your query to strings, because it knows that the SQL schema says that the 代码 field is a TEXT field and so it is correcting your query for you. (Which it should not do -- the number 1 is NOT the same as the string "1" and the one should NOT be converted into the other unless the user *specifically* asks for that conversion, but that's a rant about bad software design, which doesn't help answer your question.) So this "feature" of sqlitemanager (that's really a bug) is hiding the problem in your query, but the pysqlite3 library does not auto-convert data types and so it is exposing the problem.

Regardless of whether sqlitemanager's behavior is the right thing or not, the solution to your problem is very simple: make sure that when you're searching for a value in a TEXT field such as 代码, that you give it a search value that is a text string, enclosed in quotes. That will work everywhere, in both Python and in sqlitemanager, and so that's the way you want to write your queries.

Comment: maybe the reason is not true,all the sql format can be done in sqlitemanager ,but wrapped it in python sqlite3 ,it can not be done,i have shrink my database from 250M into 12M ,you can download it and have a test .

Comment: @it_is_a_literature - The example SELECT query that you posted in sqlitemanager is also searching for an integer (no quotes around the number 300001). Try putting quotes around the 300001 in sqlitemanager, and see if that makes your query fail. If it does, then the integer/string distinction is your problem.

Comment: i quote the number 300001 as '300001' ,and get the right answer .

Comment: Wait, I got things backwards. Looking at your database, your "代码" fields are all TEXT fields, and the "code" field of your "quote" table is also a TEXT field. So I still think my answer is correct that the problem is integers vs. strings, but the code *without* quotation marks should have failed and the code *with* quotation marks should have worked. (Which is indeed what you said in your question). That still leaves the mystery of why sqlitemanager is working when the query is searching for the wrong data type.

Comment: I believe that sqlitemanager is hiding the problem in your query by silently converting the integer 300001 to the string '300001' behind the scenes, whereas the pysqlite3 library isn't doing any data type conversions. If that's true, then sqlitemanager is doing the *wrong* thing, converting the user's data without informing him, and I would consider that a bug. Which means that one bug is hiding another bug.

Comment: At any rate, I've given you the answer that I believe *very strongly* is correct: that SQLite makes a distinction between text and numbers. Your 代码 fields are given as TEXT fields in your SQL schema, so your SQL queries need to search for text (with quotation marks) rather than numbers if you want to get the right results. The sqlitemanager program is hiding the problem from you, but the Python library is not. And that's the answer to your question about why your Python code works when you use '300001' and not when you use 300001.

Comment: I have quoted '300001' in my pysqlite3 query ,but can not get the right result ,why?

Comment: I don't know. If the string vs. integer type difference isn't the problem, then I don't have enough information to solve your problem. Could you give me a little more information? What is the text of the query after you quote the '300001'? Is it exactly the same as the "code1" query in your question? Also, what is the right result that it should be producing? And what is the actual (wrong) result that it's producing?

Comment: i am sorry for my wrong telling ,when quoted as `300001` ,after  3 mininutes , right query result displayed on my console.

Comment: Good, then you should be able to solve any further problems like this by making sure that you quote the search values for TEXT fields like 代码. If you've found my answer useful, please don't forget to check the green check box to "accept" the answer: that will tell anyone else who finds your question later (in a Google search, for example) that this answer solved your problem, and will probably solve their problem as well.

Comment: 代码  have more meaning ,it is sure that it has souce code meaning in some context, but here in my context ,it is the meaning of symbol,such as `c` is the symbol of citibank in us stock market.